# Mongoose: how to only populate, sort and return a nested object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a User schema, with a `messages` array. The `message` array is filled by conversations id and referenced to a `Conversation` schema.

I want to fetch all conversations from a user, sort them by unread and then most recent messages. Finally, I must only return an array of `lastMessage` object.

For the moment, I have only managed to populate the whole user object.

Here is the Conversation Schema:

```js
const conversationSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    messages: [{ message: { type: String }, authorId: { type: String } }],
    lastMessage: {
      authorId: { type: String },
      snippet: { type: String },
      read: { type: Boolean },
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

conversationSchema.index({ name: 1 });

module.exports = mongoose.model("Conversation", conversationSchema);
```

And here is my code:

```js
router.get("/conversations", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { userId } = req.query;
    const user = await User.findById({ _id: userId }).populate("messages");
    .sort({ updatedAt: 1, "lastMessage.read": 1 });
    return res.json({ messages: user.messages });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("error", err);
    return res.json({ errorType: "unread-messages-list" });
  }
});
```

How to do this?